# How to return object from angularJS service AFTER http request is complete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm implementing a small service for my angularJS app that makes an http request to my server for a couple of text posts. Here's my current implementation:

```
app.factory("postFetcher", ['$http', function($http){
  var posts; 

  $http.get('https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/k2mwszledbge/entries?access_token=afa8ba8572bb0232644d94c80cfd4ae01314cd0589b98551147aab50f7134e30')
    .then(function(response){
      posts = response.data.items;
    });

  return {
    getList: function(){
      return posts; 
    }
  }
}]);
```

The problem with this is that the http request is not complete by the time that the `posts` array is returned. My intuition tells me to place the return function within the http `.then` function so that it is only returned once the request is complete, however this isn't allowed.

Is there a way I can delay the return of `posts` until the http request is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return a promise to the caller. That way, the caller can "listen" to the promise. In order to return just `posts`, you have to append a `then` which returns `response.data.items`. The `then` that gets chained afterwards resolves that value.

```
getList: function(){
  return $http.get(...).then(function(response){
    // resolve just `response.data.items` to the next attached then which
    // would be from the caller of getList
    return response.data.items;
  });
}
```

That way, the caller can also attach a `then` from the promise:

```
postFetcher.getList().then(function(posts){
  // use `posts` (which is response.data.items)
});
```

---

In order to just call it once, you could store the promise in a variable. Then have `getList` return that promise. Attaching `then` to already resolved promises should resolve immediately to the resolved value.

```
var posts =  $http.get(...).then(function(response){
  return response.data.items;
});

return {
  getList: function(){
    return posts;
  }
}

// Call getList() the same way as above
```

Comment: Nice, this makes sense. However, is there a way to keep the http request outside of the return function?

Comment: Awesome. One last question if you don't mind. When you store the `$http.get` into `posts`, is the query actually being executed? Or is it not being executed until i call `getList()` in my controller?

Comment: @ByronS it's executed when the factory is created.

Comment: In your example, inside the second then function the posts parameter is not the value returned from the first then. It is the same value received in "response"

Answer (score 3):

Use [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) it's one way that I see:
Factory:

```
app.factory("postFetcher", ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    var posts; 

    return {
        getList: getListFn
    };

    function getListFn(){
        var defer=$q.defer();

        $http.get('https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/k2mwszledbge/entries?access_token=afa8ba8572bb0232644d94c80cfd4ae01314cd0589b98551147aab50f7134e30')
        .then(function(response){
            if(response && response.data && response.data.items){
                posts = response.data.items;
                defer.resolve(posts);
            }
        });

        return defer.promise;
    };        
}]);
```

Use in controllers:

```
postFetcher.getList().then(function(data){
//data processing;
});
```